# Canvas fill viewport and keep image ratio

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make the canvas area and image fill the viewport without the image stretching and retain its aspect ratio when you resize the page. Below is my current code.

```
      var ctx = $("#demo")[0].getContext("2d"),
      img = new Image(),
      radius = 35,
      blurryImageSrc = "https://s9.postimg.cc/u9nsmzlwf/image.jpg";

      img.src = blurryImageSrc;

      $(img).on("load", function() {

      resizeCanvas();

       $("#demo").on("mousemove", function(e) {
        erase(getXY(e));
       });

       $("#reset").on("click", function() {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
       });

       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, window.innerWidth,  window.innerHeight);
       ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
     });

    function getXY(e) {
     var r = $("#demo")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
     return { x: e.clientX - r.left, y: e.clientY - r.top };
    }

    function erase(pos) {
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.fill();
    }


      var can = document.getElementById('demo');
      function resizeCanvas() {
        can.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
         setTimeout(function() {
          can.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
         }, 0);
      }

      window.onresize = resizeCanvas;

      resizeCanvas();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65fph0mn/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retain the image's correct proportions, you need to query it's 'natural' width and height. The `image` object itself has two properties for this purpose: **naturalWidth** and **naturalHeight**.

As the image finished loading you must decide by which factor to scale the image based on the dimensions of the browser window and the longer side of your image.

Let's have a look at a simple example. Say your browser window's width is 1200 pixel and the image 250. If we now divide 1200 by 250 we get 4.8 - that's the factor we need to multiply the image's width **and** height to fill the current browser window in one direction while maintaining it's correct aspect ratio.

Here's an example:

```js
var ctx = $("#demo")[0].getContext("2d"),
  img = new Image(),
  radius = 35,
  blurryImageSrc = "https://s9.postimg.cc/u9nsmzlwf/image.jpg";

/// setup logic
img.src = blurryImageSrc;

$(img).on("load", function() {
  resizeCanvas();
});

var can = document.getElementById('demo');

function resizeCanvas() {
  can.width = window.innerWidth;
  can.height = window.innerHeight;
  if (img.width > 0) {
    let factor = can.width / img.naturalWidth * img.naturalHeight > window.innerHeight ? can.height / img.naturalHeight : can.width / img.naturalWidth;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth * factor, img.naturalHeight * factor);
  }
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;

resizeCanvas();
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#demo {
  cursor: crosshair;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="demo" width=640 height=640></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm waiting for the image to load. Then I can add the eventlistener for window resize and call the function resizeCanvas. This function will then resize the canvas and paint the image in the canvas.

The image must be repainted every time the window is resized.

To keep the aspect ratio the height of the image is calculated from the scaled width.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('demo');

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  img = new Image(),
  blurryImageSrc = "https://s9.postimg.cc/u9nsmzlwf/image.jpg";

img.src = blurryImageSrc;

img.addEventListener("load", e => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
  resizeCanvas();
});

function paint() {
  var newHeight = Math.round(img.width/canvas.width*img.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, newHeight, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  paint();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#demo {
  cursor: crosshair;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="demo" width="640" height="640"></canvas>
</div>
```